# SNP_SESSION table in ODI does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle-data-integrator

The given query

```
SELECT * 
FROM SNP_SESSION 
WHERE SESS_NO = '#Odi_SessionId'
```

throws an error in ODI:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: SNP_SESSION table is automatically generated table which contains all session details right ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely reasons for seeing this error.

1. You lack the proper SELECT access to the database in question.
2. (And more likely) You need to add the schema to the query (or even possibly the database name). For instance:

(If your schema is "dbo")

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.SNP_SESSION 
WHERE SESS_NO = '#Odi_SessionId'
```

Comment: I have already added the schema to the query. Still the error exist.

Comment: Then the most likely problem is that you do not have the proper access to the table at this time. Inquire with your DBA how to accomplish that.

Comment: SNP_SESSION table is automatically generated table which contains all session details right ?